# scrapy : find element which has particular text

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl. I am getting whole content of website.

```
import scrapy
import os

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "team"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='http://*****.com', callback=self.get_scripts)

    def get_scripts(self, response):
        print response.css("body").extract()

    def get_scripts(self, response):
        print response.css("body").extract()
```

Now i am searching for a text, which i can get by simple search text/sub-string by python. What i want is to select that selector where this text match. Please let know what is the best way to do this.

Comment: _"What i want is to select that selector where this text match."_ Please clarify your question with sample input HTML, what selector you tried, whar you got and what you expected instead.

Comment: **The BEST way** to do that is to read Scrapys documentation on [Selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) first.

Comment: <div class="one-half fullwidth-dark-bg">
<h1><span style="color: #a1923a;">pritam parua</span></h1>
<p>some description</p>
<p>some description</p>
</div>      I don't know the selector.. i want that selector which has text 'pritam parua'

Answer (score 26):

You can do something like this.

```
response.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'MY TEXT')]").getall()
```

It will return list of all items containing `MY TEXT`

Comment: getting error  "The functional pseudo-element ::contains() is unknown"